# what is the difference between these two configurations?

Tags: amplifier, bjt, sound, power-amplifier

I can understand this circuit configuration:

[image: AB net]

But i don't understand when signal is placed in Qp's base.

[image: AB sedra]

In this configuration we don't have VBB/2 in the two base...
Sorry about my english and thanks in advance.

Comment: The diodes are there to keep the two BJTs' bases separated by enough voltage so that the cross-over distortion is relatively minor. Which end of the diode pair you drive (or the middle) doesn't matter nearly so much (assuming the rest of the arrangement permits it, of course.) The schematic with the current source is ***much better*** for an entirely different reason -- the resistors do a poor job of sourcing/sinking necessary base current drive when driven further towards the rails. Not at all desirable to use resistors. Current source is much better for that (and other reasons.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two circuits are both based on emitter followers. As you may recall, the emitter follower has a gain of about 1 and an offset of one base-emitter voltage, Vbe. The followers are arranged as a complementary pair.

In both cases the purpose of the diodes D1 and D2 is to insert a bias that parallels the Vbe of each transistor. (Vbe is about the same as a diode drop, 0.7V.) Since there’s two Vbe in opposite polarity, the net difference between the two bases is 2*|Vbe|, or about 1.4V.

As each circuit operates, the top and bottom of the diode pair track the input, with an offset of 1.4V with respect to each other. In circuit 2, the input is simply driving Qp as an emitter follower directly, Qn’s base will be 1.4V above it.

The second circuit has the advantage of being DC coupled, though with an offset of one -Vbe input to output. The first circuit on the other hand is AC coupled, but is self-biasing for single-ended operation.

Try simulating this in LTSpice to see what is going on. LTSpice is free to download and has a good library of parts to work with.